# Tensorflow: What's the best practice to get a section of a manual from a question?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, text-classification

I would like to use Tensorflow to create a smart faq. I've seen how to manage a chatbot, but my need is to let the user searching for help and the result  must be the most probable chapter or section of a manual.

For example the user can ask:

> "What are the O.S. supported?"

The reply must be a list of all the possible sections of the manual in which could be the correct answer.
My text record set for the training procedure is only the manual itself. I've followed the text classification example, but i don't think is what i need because in that case it would  only understand if a given text belongs to a category or another one.

What's the best practice to accomplish this task (i use Python)?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea could be building [embeddings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding) of your text using [Bert](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805) or other pretrained models (take a look to [transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers)) and later compare (for instance using cosine distance) such embeddings with your query (the question) and get the most similar ones interpreting as the section or chapter containing them.

Comment: I've resumed this job after some time and tried your suggestion. Seems to work pretty well! I've used the **distiluse-base-multilingual-cased** as model and then embed my data. Even if it's very accurate, some times the result is not what is expected: i issue three different responses ordered by scores and often the right one isn't at first place. Is it possible to fine tune the model remembering the right response for the next queries? I.E.: at first query the right response is at position 3 (and the user flag it as right), the next time i would like it could have higher score. Thank you!

Comment: As you can collect data about the user's selection you can use that information as refinement of your ranking function, so that your final rank is a proper combination of the document score and user data.